# Mocha tests TypeScript strange TypeError

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

Mocha was working perfectly fine on my TypeScript-based code. But out of the blue, it started behaving strangely. Even rolling back to a previous commit didn't solve it.

The error seems to pop at compiling (so not related to Unit test code but mocha config?).
Here it is...

in polyfill.js :

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible
at Function.assign (<anonymous>)
```

Here is my VSCode launch.json:

```
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Mocha PD",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": ["-r", "ts-node/register", "--timeout", "999999", "--colors", "${workspaceFolder}/test/**/pipedrive*.test.ts"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "protocol": "inspector"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I got past this by unchecking the Caught Exceptions in the Breakpoints panel.

Comment: Disabling exceptions doesn't seem like a good idea...